# php string attachement - attach csv from a string to an email

Tags: php, email

I want to rewrite the code below to generate a string. This string I want to attach to an eamil. It should appear as a csv file.

```
$fh = fopen($file,'w');

    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals, ';', '"');

    }
   array_walk($aData, '__outputCSV', $fh);
   fclose($fh);
```

Any idea's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [attach file to email using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578389/attach-file-to-email-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious and lazy approach would be not to rewrite it, but to simply create a temp file and call `file_get_contents()` on it afterwards.

This, however, would be boring, so I'm going to suggest what is arguably an over complicated approach, but it should work nicely and will be done entirely in memory:

Use [this class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) that is provided in the PHP manual as an example of how to write a custom protocol handler, and the following example code:

```
function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
    fputcsv($filehandler, $vals, ';', '"');
}

stream_wrapper_register("var", "VariableStream");

$myCSVdata = "";

$fh = fopen('var://myCSVdata', 'w');
array_walk($aData, '__outputCSV', $fh);
fclose($fh);

echo $myCSVdata; // Ta Da!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to get a MIME compatible email class that can send emails with attachments. I recall using RMail or PHPMimeMail a while back, you'll have to google it.

Else, you'll need to learn how to build MIME mail yourself. But for all the trouble that it's worth i'll really recommend you to get a class that already does that for you.

EDIT:

I didn't understand your question at first, maybe you should completly reformat and change your title. Here is my suggestion:

```
$data = '';
foreach($aData as $aDataLine) {
    foreach($aDataLine as $aDataKey => $aDataField) {
        $aDataLine[$aDataKey] = '"'.str_replace('"', '\\"', $aDataField).'"';
    }
    $data .= implode(',', $aDataLine)."\n";
}
//$data contains your CSV
```

I dont think i forgot anything, it SHOULD work out of the box...

Comment: I am going to send it with Zend_Mail. That's not the problem. The thing is to get the right string.