# Send a attach file in a email using php

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [attach file to email using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578389/attach-file-to-email-using-php)

i am using the following code to send a attached file in a email

```
 <?php

//to get the file extention
function getExtension($str)
{
    $i = strrpos($str,".");
    if (!$i) { return ""; }
    $l = strlen($str) - $i;
    $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
    return $ext;
}


//To Upload a file 
function upload_image()
{
  $newname="";



 if ($_FILES["resume_upload"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
    {


    $filename = $_FILES['resume_upload']['name'];
    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    $image_name=uniqid('img').'.'.$extension;
    $newname=$image_name;
    $temp_name=$_FILES['resume_upload']['tmp_name'];
    $copied = copy($temp_name, $newname);
return $newname;


}


}





$filename=upload_image();

echo "the file name :".$filename;


//$filename="";
$path ="";
$mailto="test@gmail.com";
$from_mail="test@gmail.com";
$from_name="test";
$replyto ="test@gmail.com";
$subject="test mail";
$message="test message";

mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message);

function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
  //  $file = $path.$filename;
  $file=$filename;
    $file_size = filesize($file);

$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";


echo "end ofmail";
    if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        $msg = "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
    } else {
        $msg = "mail send ... ERROR!";
    }


}










?>
```

I am uploading the file to server . I need to send the uploaded file as attachment in php email.

The above code not able to sending the attach mail. could any one please suggest something to achieve this in php?

Comment: Problem with atttachment? or with sending mail?

Comment: i thick i am asking for the what would be problem in above code?

Comment: @MAK: Why not replacing it with a working version? Code has been outlined in other questions. Also you should hightlight the line where you first see the problem happening. This needs basic debugging first. Introduce error checks, check return values etc.. Your job before you ask. Reduce the code to the problem part.

Answer (score 0):

I compile this a sometime ago. hope it helps.

```
<?php
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$separator = md5(time());


 function mime_content_type($filename) {

        $mime_types = array(

            'txt' => 'text/plain',
            'htm' => 'text/html',
            'html' => 'text/html',
            'php' => 'text/html',
            'css' => 'text/css',
            'js' => 'application/javascript',
            'json' => 'application/json',
            'xml' => 'application/xml',
            'swf' => 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
            'flv' => 'video/x-flv',

            // images
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
            'bmp' => 'image/bmp',
            'ico' => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
            'tiff' => 'image/tiff',
            'tif' => 'image/tiff',
            'svg' => 'image/svg+xml',
            'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml',

            // archives
            'zip' => 'application/zip',
            'rar' => 'application/x-rar-compressed',
            'exe' => 'application/x-msdownload',
            'msi' => 'application/x-msdownload',
            'cab' => 'application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed',

            // audio/video
            'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
            'qt' => 'video/quicktime',
            'mov' => 'video/quicktime',

            // adobe
            'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
            'psd' => 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop',
            'ai' => 'application/postscript',
            'eps' => 'application/postscript',
            'ps' => 'application/postscript',

            // ms office
            'doc' => 'application/msword',
            'rtf' => 'application/rtf',
            'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
            'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',

            // open office
            'odt' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
            'ods' => 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
        );

        $ext = strtolower(array_pop(explode('.',$filename)));
        if (array_key_exists($ext, $mime_types)) {
            return $mime_types[$ext];
        }
        elseif (function_exists('finfo_open')) {
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
            $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
            finfo_close($finfo);
            return $mimetype;
        }
        else {
            return 'application/octet-stream';
        }
    }

$file = array('mime' => mime_content_type($filename), 'name' => $filename, 'data' => chunk_split(base64_encode($filename)));


// Basic Header Input

$to='';
$cc='';
$bcc='';
$your_email = 'John@doe.com';
$to = 'Jane@doe.com';
$subject='A subject';
$from = 'The Matrix';
$message='What ever dot.com';
$headers  = "From: ".$your_email." <$from>".$eol;

$headers .= "Cc: $cc" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "Bcc: $bcc" . "\r\n"; 

// main header

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
$headers_to_rep .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers_to_rep .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";

// no more headers after this, we start the body! //

$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;


// message
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;

// attachment

$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: ".$file['mime']."; name=\"".$file['name']."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $file['data'].$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;

if(!mail($to, $subject, $body,$headers)) {
  echo "Mailer Error: ";
} else {

  echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```