# how to send and audio file via an email using joomla or php

Tags: php, joomla

I want people to upload audio and send  the audio via email how feasible is the idea
or showing  audio list on joomla or php website and sending them audio link in email when they click on particular list
how to go about the idea?
joomla should be used or pure php?
any help?

it should not be a complicated website

Comment: Well of course, if you're using Joomla, try to make full use of the Joomla API. Personally, I would recommend emailing them a link to the site rather than sending them the actual audio file as it might start causing server overloads if too many emails are sent. Have a read of the Joomla documentation to get an idea of how the mailer class works

Comment: any extensions that can be used? the flow of system? i have no clue how to start? i want to be crystal clear bout how concrete the idea will work and then implement it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852696/send-a-attach-file-in-a-email-using-php

Comment: There are no "out the box" extensions I know of that have you exact requirements. There might be 1 or 2 poking around on the Joomla Extensions Directory, have a look there